# admin Confirmation before modify record

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, database-design, hibernate-envers

I have a J2EE enterprise project. In the project we used Maven, Hibernate/JPA, Spring, ZK and other frameworks.

for the saving audits, i used hibernate envers.
I want the upper user(ex: admin) to be able to confirm the record changes before they are finalized .(I know it is possible to use temporary tables like hibernate envers audition tables)

Is it possible to do this by customizing hibernate envers?

otherwise is there any framework for this work?

Answer (score 0):

Envers isn't a workflow library, so you can't implement any form of approval processes using it. It only audits data changes.

If you want a workflow, you should model this explicitly in the entities and/or use frameworks which help with that.

Comment: i know envers is a framework for audition, but i think i will can customize it for this work.
what frameworks you suggests?

Comment: I'm not really up-to-date, the workflow frameworks from some years ago where e.g. jBPM or some module of Drools, but I'm not sure how these evolved.

Comment: I don't want to use BPMS or any workflow , i want a framework like https://github.com/liveeditor/draftsman.